# Macro VBA buscar informações em site

Tags: internet-explorer, vba, microsoft-excel

Preciso buscar informações em um site de imóveis e trazê-las para o excel. Fiz a macro abaixo:

```
Sub zap()

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

With ie
.Navigate "http://www.zap.com.br/imoveis/fipe-zap/"
.Visible = True
End With

Do While ie.Busy
Loop
Do While ie.readyState <> 4
Loop
Call aguarda

Dim CurrentWindow As HTMLWindowProxy: Set CurrentWindow = ie.Document.parentWindow

'SELECIONA O NUMERO DE DORMITORIOS:  (0)=Todos  (1)=1 dormitório  (2)=2 dormitórios  (3)=3 dormitórios  (4)=4 dormitórios
ie.Document.All.Item("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$quartosFipe")(0).Checked = True

'SELECIONA O PERÍODO:  (0)=Ano corrente  (1)=Últimos 12 meses  (2) =Todo o período
ie.Document.All.Item("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$")(2).Checked = True

'SELECIONA SE É VENDA OU ALUGUEL:  (0)=Venda  (1)=Aluguel
ie.Document.All.Item("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$radTransacao")(0).Checked = True

'SELECIONA A CIDADE:  (0)=FipeZap Ampliado  (1)=FipeZap Composto  (2)=Belo Horizonte  (3)=Brasilia  (4)=Curitiba  (5)=Florianopolis  (6)=Fortaleza  (7)=Niteroi  (8)=Porto Alegre  (9)=Recife  (10)=Rio de Janeiro  (11)=Salvador  (12)=Santo Andre  (13)=São Bernardo do Campo  (14)=São Caetano do Sul  (15)=São Paulo  (16)=Vila Velha  (17)=Vitoria
ie.Document.All.Item("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlCidadeIndiceFipeZap")(10).Selected = True

'ATUALIZA O GRÁFICO
ie.Document.parentWindow.execScript ("javascript:AtualizaGraficoIndice()")

    For Each element In ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("circle")
    x = element.getAttribute("cx")
    y = element.getAttribute("cy")
    Workbooks("FipeZap.xlsm").Worksheets("Plan1").Range("A1000000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = x
    Workbooks("FipeZap.xlsm").Worksheets("Plan1").Range("B1000000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = y
Next



End Sub
```

Sub Aguarda:

```
Sub aguarda()
newHour = Hour(Now())
newMinute = Minute(Now())
newSecond = Second(Now()) + 1
waitTime = TimeSerial(newHour, newMinute, newSecond)
Application.Wait waitTime
End Sub
```

Entretanto, nem todos os valores retornados pelo site batem com os valores inspecionados no gráfico. Apesar da coluna B bater os valores, os valores da coluna A não batem em nenhum deles.

**Alguém sabe dizer se é um problema da macro (acredito que não) ou se estou deixando passar algum ajuste que o ZAP Imoveis está fazendo na página antes de plottar o gráfico?**

**Edição**

Pessoal, o código apenas abre o ie, faz a seleção dos critérios no gráfico e insere no excel.

Segue imagem do debug da página do zap e o retorno da macro.

Uma das informações não é trazida fielmente. Veja na tela abaixo, a informação sublinhada é trazida corretamente, enquanto a informação circulada vem errada.

http://s28.postimg.org/pil3834dp/tela_ie.png

http://s8.postimg.org/p7oykz2ud/tela_excel.png

Comment: Esse é o crawler mais original que eu já vi. Parabéns!

Comment: Pergunta muito interessante. Mas, pra facilitar, seria bacana você "explicar" o seu código um pouco (nem todo mundo vai ter saco de interpretar o código passo-a-passo). Bom, eu notei que você força a execução da função `AtualizaGraficoIndice`. Eu presumo que seja ela quem atualize os dados do gráfico, estou certo? Uma pergunta meio óbvia então: será que o resultado dessa execução é atualizado no conteúdo (HTML) do seu objeto `ie` no VBA? Eu dei uma olhada na documentação (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536420(v=vs.85).aspx) e não diz nada sobre o conteúdo ser atualizado...

Comment: Outra coisa, você chegou a colocar uns `Debug.Print` pra exibir os valores de `x` e `y` no seu laço sobre os elementos `circle`? (só pra garantir que o problema não é formatação no Excel). Aliás, se vc incluir na pergunta imagens (*screenshots*) dos valores da página e do Excel vai facilitar no entendimento das diferenças (e talvez evitar perguntas bobas como, possivelmente, essa minha. hehehe).

Comment: Luiz, o javascript atualiza o gráfico e exibe os valores de x e y no corpo do HTML dentro de elementos "circle". Quando inspecionado os valores estão lá, corretamente.

Comment: Fico feliz que você tenha encontrado a solução. Mas, cara, sua questão ainda está bastante confusa. Na imagem do IE que você adicionou eu não encontrei o elemento de id `highcharts-Series` e muito menos elementos com a tag `circle`. Além disso, os valores que você aponta como certos ou errados não têm uma ordem fácil de se interpretar se o leitor não perceber/entender o `Range("A1000000").End(xlUp)` no laço do código que você não explicou. Não leve a mal esse comentário, a minha intenção é ajudar para que a sua questão fique realmente interessante para outras pessoas além de você mesmo. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

já achei a solução.

**Na verdade, o ZAP Imoveis trabalha com SVG na seção do gráfico.**

Minha macro recolhe a informação dos pontos coordenada x do Internet Explorer, porém há alguma diferença na implementação do gráfico em SVG do IE para a versão do site no Chrome (onde estava inspecionando elementos).

Além dessa diferença de implementação do SVG entre browsers, alterei o código em algumas seções, pois ele estava atualizando os valores do grádico antes que o gráfico tivesse carregado por completo. Como trata-se de um SVG com animação, ao trocar as opções, a animação mudava os valores cx e cy dinamicamente e estes estavam sendo capturados pela macro antes de atingirem o seu valor definitivo.

Segue a macro final. É um ótimo exemplo de crawler e pode ser aproveitado facilmente no futuro.

Grande abraço!

```
Sub zap()

Dim ie As Object
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate "http://www.zap.com.br/imoveis/fipe-zap/"
    End With


Do Until (ie.readyState = 4 And Not ie.Busy)
    DoEvents
Loop

Dim CurrentWindow As HTMLWindowProxy: Set CurrentWindow = ie.Document.parentWindow

'SELECIONA O NUMERO DE DORMITORIOS:  (0)=Todos  (1)=1 dormitório  (2)=2 dormitórios  (3)=3 dormitórios  (4)=4 dormitórios
ie.Document.All.Item("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$quartosFipe")(1).Checked = True

'SELECIONA O PERÍODO:  (0)=Ano corrente  (1)=Últimos 12 meses  (2) =Todo o período
ie.Document.All.Item("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$")(0).Checked = True

'SELECIONA SE É VENDA OU ALUGUEL:  (0)=Venda  (1)=Aluguel
ie.Document.All.Item("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$radTransacao")(0).Checked = True

'SELECIONA A CIDADE:  (0)=FipeZap Ampliado  (1)=FipeZap Composto  (2)=Belo Horizonte  (3)=Brasilia  (4)=Curitiba  (5)=Florianopolis  (6)=Fortaleza  (7)=Niteroi  (8)=Porto Alegre  (9)=Recife  (10)=Rio de Janeiro  (11)=Salvador  (12)=Santo Andre  (13)=São Bernardo do Campo  (14)=São Caetano do Sul  (15)=São Paulo  (16)=Vila Velha  (17)=Vitoria
ie.Document.All.Item("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlCidadeIndiceFipeZap")(10).Selected = True

'ATUALIZA O GRÁFICO
ie.Document.parentWindow.execScript ("javascript:AtualizaGraficoIndice()")

'AGUARDA A ATUALIZAÇÃO
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:06"))

For Each element In ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("circle")
    x = element.getAttribute("cx")
    y = element.getAttribute("cy")
    Workbooks("FipeZap.xlsm").Worksheets("Plan1").Range("A1000000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = x
    Workbooks("FipeZap.xlsm").Worksheets("Plan1").Range("B1000000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = y
Next

End Sub
```